# Pass variables to multiple view in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-blade, laravel-views

I want to pass a variable to multiple view bu when i use share method in View. Its says the share method isn't find on View.

How you say i use it and i try the composer either but no matter how i try it can't work could you give me simple example of this action

My controller `categorycontroller.php`

```
public function site(){
    $data =  array();
    $data['subcategories']  =  SubCategory::all();
    $data['categories']     =  Category::all();
    return view('template.sitemap',compact("data"));
}
```

My route `web.php`

```
Route::get('/404.html', function () {
    return view('template/404');
})->name('404.html');

Route::get('404.html','CategoryController@site')->name('404');

Route::get('/sitemap.html', function () {
    return view('template/sitemap');
})->name('sitemap.html');

Route::get('sitemap.html','CategoryController@site')->name('sitemap');
```

what do you suggest?

Comment: i try to use View Share method but it isn't defined in view.

Comment: What's your Laravel version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a variable accessible in multiple views using one of these methods for example:

AppServiceProvider ( reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers ) with ViewComposer ( reference: https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers )

You'll need to add to your ServiceProvider boot() method something similar to this:

```
public function boot()
{
    View::share('variable_name', 'some_value_here');
}
```

Or inside a controller:

```
public function __construct() {
  $something = 'just a test';
  View::share('something', $something);
}
```

Comment: i try to do things you say but i got this error before i even ran the project



> php artisan serve

In Macroable.php line 75:
                                                      
  Method Illuminate\View\View::share does not exist.

Comment: What Laravel version are you using? You should use this trait:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

Comment: laravel 5.6 version
and yet i recive "Method Illuminate\View\View::share does not exist."

Comment: `View` is not `Illuminate\View\View` it is the facade, always  `View` or `Illuminate\Support\Facades\View`